# How to connect Spatialite with Google Map on Adrioid

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, spatialite

I am decided to create an application that can pass the coordinates data stored in Spatialite data to the Google Map for Android for marker display.

Answer (score -1):

Use `spatialite-android` in your app.
You can download binaries [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android) and add `*.so` files in your app's `lib` folder.
How to connect, work with spatial data, you can guide yourself by exemples from [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial)

Comment: Missing examples links?